# Google Reviews Snippet VS Aggregate Ratings

Tags: google-rich-snippets, google-schemas, rich-snippets

I have a few questions about what happens if I add both "aggregate reviews" and "review snippets" schema to a webpage.

1. Will the aggregate number of "votes" and the aggregate vote rating be displaced by the number and average rating of the review snippets?
2. Is it possible for both to appear at the same time on SERP, with the aggregate votes & average score (1-5) appearing above the review snippets?

Review Snippet Sample:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org/",
      "@type": "Product",
      "brand": {
        "@type": "Brand",
        "name": "Penguin Books"
      },
      "description": "The Catcher in the Rye is a classic coming-of-age story: an story of teenage alienation, capturing the human need for connection and the bewildering sense of loss as we leave childhood behind.",
      "sku": "9780241984758",
      "mpn": "925872",
      "image": "http://www.example.com/catcher-in-the-rye-book-cover.jpg",
      "name": "The Catcher in the Rye",
      "review": [{
        "@type": "Review",
        "reviewRating": {
          "@type": "Rating",
          "ratingValue": "5"
        },
        "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "John Doe"
        },
        "reviewBody": "I really enjoyed this book. It captures the essential challenge people face as they try make sense of their lives and grow to adulthood."
      },
      {
        "@type": "Review",
        "reviewRating": {
          "@type": "Rating",
          "ratingValue": "1"
        },
        "author": {
          "@type": "Person",
          "name": "Jane Doe"
        },
        "reviewBody": "I really didn't care for this book."
      }],
      "aggregateRating": {
        "@type": "AggregateRating",
        "ratingValue": "88",
        "bestRating": "100",
        "ratingCount": "20"
      },
      "offers": {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "https://example.com/offers/catcher-in-the-rye",
        "priceCurrency": "USD",
        "price": "5.99",
        "priceValidUntil": "2020-11-05",
        "itemCondition": "https://schema.org/UsedCondition",
        "availability": "https://schema.org/InStock",
        "seller": {
          "@type": "Organization",
          "name": "eBay"
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Aggregate Ratings Sample

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
  {
    "@context": "https://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Executive Anvil",
    "image": [
      "https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg",
      "https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg",
      "https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg"
     ],
    "brand": {
      "@type": "Thing",
      "name": "ACME"
    },
    "aggregateRating": {
      "@type": "AggregateRating",
      "ratingValue": "4.4",
      "ratingCount": "89"
    },
    "offers": {
      "@type": "AggregateOffer",
      "lowPrice": "119.99",
      "highPrice": "199.99",
      "priceCurrency": "USD"
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: I see that the aggregateRating is the important one for review star rich snippets. Maybe the review entities help confirm that the information is valid. Have you seen snippets that show more details about individual reviews?

Comment: No not a single one @TonyMcCreath